# Retrieve IEnumerable's method parameters

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Consider this method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetList(int Count)
{
    foreach (var X in Y)
    {
        // do a lot of expensive stuff here (e.g. traverse a large HTML document)
        // when we reach "Count" then exit out of the foreach loop
    }
}
```

and I'd call it like so: `Class.GetList(10);` which would return 10 items - this is fine.

I'd like to use `IEnumerable`'s `Take()` method by using `Class.GetList().Take(10)` instead and I want the foreach loop to be able to somehow grab the number I passed into `Take()` - is this possible? It seems a more cleaner approach as it's ultimately less expensive as I can grab a full list with `Class.GetList()` once and then use `IEnumerable`'s methods to grab x items afterwards.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by implementing your method as an iterator block:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetList()
{
    foreach (var X in Y)
    {
        // do something
        yield return something;
    }
}
```

When you call `Take(10)` only the first 10 elements will be yielded - the rest of the method won't be run.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after. Nice and easy when you know how :-).

Answer (score 4):

In your `GetList` method use [`yield return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx). This way you will be able to use `Take(10)` without the `GetList` method returning the entire result first.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. However, what `Take(10)` does is that it just gets 10 items of the `Enumerable`. What you are trying to accomplish with the `Count` check, the `Take()` does this for you because it will simply stop getting items from your enumerator when it has 10 items.